# Detect changed to a GIT bare repo

Tags: git

I have a bare repo on network drive and two clients clone the php projects to their own PC.
All of them are operate by TortoiseGIT.

Suppose Client A and Client B have same revision copy.

1. A make some change on index.php.
2. Commit to their own repo and then push to the bare repo.

However , on the Client B project folder, the changed file still make as update (a green icon with tick).

Does it anyway Client B will have a notify or make change the overlay icon from TortoiseGIT in realtime?

Why i want to do this,because our clients need to do git fetch command and view log before they start working.

They can be git merge before start working instead of solve the conflict later.

Comment: It looks like you would the clones to behave as if they were in the same directory (like everybody working in same checkout). This isn't recommended (for any VCS really) and fetching/pulling the latest changes when ready is the superior approach.

Comment: You should just `git pull` on the other clients. You could look at `git hooks` for some ways to automate this /to an extent/ but (a) I don't think it is generally used on Windows, (b) it has limitations regarding checked-out branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIT is a distributed version control system. That means that each local repository can - and does - work independently. Only when doing a fetch, pull or push does it contact another repository.

A local repository doesn't care about the actual state of any configured remote repository unless explicitly told via fetch or pull. There is no way in GIT to achieve what you want to do.
You could achieve this via a combination of hooks (in the bare repository) and scripts (in each developers machine), but I would advise against it.

---

BTW: For most centralized version control systems, like SVN for example, this works just the same: You have to do an update before the working copy knows that the server has a changed version.

Comment: Thanks you for answer,so GIT and SVN can't do that, how about TFS? Or any VCS support this function?

Comment: @SilverNight: I don't know of any. However, TFS supports locking a file, i.e. to be able to edit a file you have to first check it out. If another user already checked out this file and locked it, your checkout will fail. But this only prevents to users to work on the same file at the same time. It doesn't prevent working on stale data. Just get into the habit of updating the local copy before starting work. That's how everyone else also works :)